# Create columns based on values in one column, grouped by another colum

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

My dataframe is similar to below:

```
User     type
Chris    green
Chris    brown
Chris    green
Paul     brown
Paul     brown
Mary     yellow
Mary     green
Paul     green
Chris    yellow
Mary     brown
```

My desired output is to get this:

```
User   green   brown   yellow
Chris  2       1       1
Paul   1       2       0
Mary   1       1       1
```

I have tried using .groupby as below:

```
.groupby("User")['type'].count()
```

But I ended up with this:

```
User     
Chris  4
Paul   3
Mary   3
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df["User"], df['type'])`